# Create new array in for loop based on a time slice

Tags: python, loops, datetime

I have a gridded dataset with lat, lon, time and then temperature being the variable. I want to look at some distributions based on decadal data. For example, let's say I want to look at Shanghai and a location in Singapore.

```
shanghai = temp.sel(latitude=31.25, longitude=121.5)
singapore = temp.sel(latitude=1.25, longitude=103.75)
```

Now I set the beginning and end date.

```
start_date1 = dt.datetime(1990,1,1)
end_date1 = dt.datetime(1999,12,31)
```

Now I want to create a loop so that I don't have to hard code in slicing both of the temperature arrays. Ideally, what would spit out of the for loop would be two new arrays with data for the 1990s with a name like the original variable `shanghai` + `90s` to create `shanghai90s`. Here is what I have.

```
names = [shanghai, singapore]

for i in range(len(names)):
    nine=names[i].sel(time=(slice(start_date1,end_date1)))
```

However, this only creates one new array with the last variable (in this case singapore). How would I fix this?

Comment: This might be because you are redefining nine every time it runs through the loop. So, whenever you run this program, nine will always be the result of the last run of the loop, which in this case is when names[i] == singapore.

Comment: How would I prevent that + be able to use the naming convention I want?

Comment: You could create a list or tuple named nine containing all of the new arrays, and use index position to access them. For example:`nine.append(names[i].sel(time=(slice(start_date1,end_date1))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to keep all of the city data in a dictionary but a quick way would be just to update the arrays to only include the dates you want:

```
names = [shanghai, singapore]

for city in names:
    city=city.sel(time=(slice(start_date1,end_date1)))
```

A dictionary approach would have you do some work up front to set up the coordinates and decades but then would let you loop through all the cities and decades to build a dictionary of all the data you want. It would look like this:

```
import datetime as dt
cities = {
    "Shangai": {"coords": [31.25, 121.5]},
    "Singapore": {"coords": [1.25, 103.75]},
    "Other City": {"coords": [15.25, 85.25]}
}

decades = {
    "1990s": {"start": dt.datetime(1990,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(1999,12,31)},
    "2000s": {"start": dt.datetime(2000,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(2009,12,31)},
    "2010s": {"start": dt.datetime(2010,1,1), "end": dt.datetime(2019,12,31)}
}

for city, location in cities.items():
    data = temp.sel(latitude=location['coords'][0], longitude=location['coords'][1])
    for decade, dates in decades.items():
        cities[city][decade] = data.sel(time=(slice(dates['start'], dates['end'])))
```

Then you can access the 90s data for Shangai like this:

```
cities["Shangai"]["1990s"]
```

It would really make your life much easier if you familiarize yourself with basic data structures like dictionaries and lists. There are tons of great tutorials. I suggest [this](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/) for dictionaries, and [this](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) for lists.

Also, to keep up with the spirit of this site, it is good etiquette to provide a MWE when you are asking questions. [Here is how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I need to avoid repetitiveness though in the names because I want to look at other decades as well. How would I use this for loop but also set the new variable name to be like something like “shanghai90s” or “singapore90s”, etc. Eventually I’ll have “shanghai90s”, “shanghai00s”, and “shanghai10s”. Edit: I’m also not familiar with dictionaries. If you don’t mind could you include a dictionary example? If not that’s okay.

Comment: Wow thank you. Definitely going to get more cozy with dictionaries.

Comment: I am running into some issues with the code you kindly provided. I got this error first : ----> 4         city[decade] = data.sel(time=(slice(dates['start'], dates['end'])))

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Then I edited it to say city[decade]+=data.... and that led to a new error:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Ooops. My mistake. Fixed it. Also fixed the second location argument. This is why it is very helpful to provide a MWE. Then people can check their answers before publishing:) (still this was my bad, buy I hope you get the idea:)